# Error Importing MySQL with JSON Data as column

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have an error while I am importing a db structure in MySQL

Error:

> [ERROR in query 14] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'json DEFAULT NULL,   `account_name` char(255)
>   DEFAULT NULL,   `account_user_id` ' at line 3 Import cancelled!

The whole exact SQL command is as follows:

> CREATE TABLE `ees_account` (   `account_business_id` int(32) NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT,   `data` json DEFAULT NULL,   `account_name` char(255)
>   DEFAULT NULL,   `account_user_id` int(32) DEFAULT '0',   `created_at`
>   timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,   `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT
>   NULL,   `account_status` int(32) DEFAULT '1',   `account_description`
>   text,   `account_website` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,   `account_address`
>   char(255) DEFAULT NULL,   `account_email` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `account_country_id` int(32) DEFAULT NULL,   `business_reference_id`
>   char(255) DEFAULT NULL,   `account_client_logo` text,
>   `client_reference_id` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY
>   (`account_business_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=45 DEFAULT
>   CHARSET=utf8;

Any idea what could be the potential cause ? I check the MySQL version which is same i.e. 5.7.17

Comment: I think there is not **json** type use **char** or **text** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue few months back and the issues was MySQL version. MariaDB 10.2 supported JSON. (Alpha version. Not recommended by Maria to production server. Only testing.)MariaDB 10.1 do not support JSON.

So if you have WAMP or XAMPP dev stack then most probably you have 10.1.16-MariaDB which doesn't support JSON. So upgrade your MySQL and it will be resolved.

Comment: Thanks a lot. yes the Maria DB version seems to be the issue as the same script was working on production where we had a different version and on my local machine its 10.1.16 so thats why its not running.